# Android switch automatically gets off when i go to another page

Tags: android

```
 <Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/light_r1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="43dp" />
```

Hey I am working on android project for which i am using switch.It stores data in firebase according to set on or off but if i set on the switch and visit another page in app and after that when i revisit the same page the status of switch sets to off automatically. I want to keep it same as is set by the user.

Comment: Use sharedpreferences to store boolean then do stuff with your switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you revisit the activity, that's crystal clear that your `switch` value will be restored to the default one, since the view is recreated.

You could handle this by saving the `Switch` value using SharedPreferences, Here is a quick demonstration.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY PREFS",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch);
mySwitch.setChecked(sharedpreferences.getBoolean("switch_value", false));
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("switch_value", isCheked);
    editor.commit();
 }
});
```

Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SwitchPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html). It will automatically save your switch state to the **Default Shared Preferences** under the key same as the id of your SwitchPreference.

This is the recommended way to save some settings. There is also the CheckboxPreference, ListPreference etc. for all the other options you might need.